# Can the Fitbit sync with a Google Nexus 10?

Tags: samsung-nexus-10, fitness

I have a Nexus 10 running Android 4.3. Can the [Fitbit](http://www.fitbit.com) sync with this device? This [compatibility page](https://help.fitbit.com/customer/portal/articles/987861-android-device-compatibility) doesn't explicitly list it, but I'm guessing it may work, based on the bluetooth requirements, which I believe are satisfied by Android 4.3. But before spending a lot of money, I'd like to be sure.

Has anyone used this combination successfully?

Comment: Just got a Fitbit One and it syncs with my N10 on Android 4.4.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I borrowed a friend's Fitbit and tried to sync it with my Nexus 10. I enabled Bluetooth. I then installed the Fitbit app and logged in as him. There is no option anywhere to sync the device.

I then logged out, and created a new account. On a compatible device, once the account is created, it prompts you to sync a Fitbit device. This question is never asked on the Nexus 10.

Circumstantial additional evidence comes from the large number of unhappy reviews citing device compatibility on the [Fitbit app page](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fitbit.FitbitMobile&hl=en).

So it is confirmed that despite the probable existence of the necessary bluetooth hardware/software, at the time of writing Fitbit devices **cannot** be synced with the Nexus 10.